# Django flatpages with tiny-mce won't work

Tags: python, django

I can't get tiny-mce to work with django flatpages.

I am using Python 2.7 and django 1.5.2

I am following the instructions at http://django-tinymce.readthedocs.org/en/latest/installation.html

The following diagram shows my directory structure https://lh3.googleusercontent.com/-QtdsQE8WOak/UhZlsKIigRI/AAAAAAAADFw/9j4oLT6v1Nw/w764-h354-no/cms.png

The flatfiles are working but I get none of the rich text editor features.

I also don't get any error message.

Below I show how I have my files.

My settings.py file is as follows:

## Django settings for cms project.

```
import os
PROJECT_DIR = os.path.dirname(__file__)

DEBUG = True
TEMPLATE_DEBUG = DEBUG

ADMINS = (
    # ('Your Name', 'your_email@example.com'),
)

MANAGERS = ADMINS

DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.sqlite3', # Add 'postgresql_psycopg2', 'mysql', 'sqlite3' or 'oracle'.
        'NAME': 'cms.db',                      # Or path to database file if using sqlite3.
        # The following settings are not used with sqlite3:
        'USER': '',
        'PASSWORD': '',
        'HOST': '',                      # Empty for localhost through domain sockets or '127.0.0.1' for localhost through TCP.
        'PORT': '',                      # Set to empty string for default.
    }
}

# Hosts/domain names that are valid for this site; required if DEBUG is False
# See https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.5/ref/settings/#allowed-hosts
ALLOWED_HOSTS = []

# Local time zone for this installation. Choices can be found here:
# http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_tz_zones_by_name
# although not all choices may be available on all operating systems.
# In a Windows environment this must be set to your system time zone.
TIME_ZONE = 'Greenwich'

# Language code for this installation. All choices can be found here:
# http://www.i18nguy.com/unicode/language-identifiers.html
LANGUAGE_CODE = 'en-gb'

SITE_ID = 1

# If you set this to False, Django will make some optimizations so as not
# to load the internationalization machinery.
USE_I18N = True

# If you set this to False, Django will not format dates, numbers and
# calendars according to the current locale.
USE_L10N = True

# If you set this to False, Django will not use timezone-aware datetimes.
USE_TZ = True

# Absolute filesystem path to the directory that will hold user-uploaded files.
# Example: "/var/www/example.com/media/"
MEDIA_ROOT = ''

# URL that handles the media served from MEDIA_ROOT. Make sure to use a
# trailing slash.
# Examples: "http://example.com/media/", "http://media.example.com/"
MEDIA_URL = ''

# Absolute path to the directory static files should be collected to.
# Don't put anything in this directory yourself; store your static files
# in apps' "static/" subdirectories and in STATICFILES_DIRS.
# Example: "/var/www/example.com/static/"
STATIC_ROOT = ''

# URL prefix for static files.
# Example: "http://example.com/static/", "http://static.example.com/"
STATIC_URL = '/static/'

# Additional locations of static files
STATICFILES_DIRS = (
    # Put strings here, like "/home/html/static" or "C:/www/django/static".
    # Always use forward slashes, even on Windows.
    # Don't forget to use absolute paths, not relative paths.
)

# List of finder classes that know how to find static files in
# various locations.
STATICFILES_FINDERS = (
    'django.contrib.staticfiles.finders.FileSystemFinder',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles.finders.AppDirectoriesFinder',
#    'django.contrib.staticfiles.finders.DefaultStorageFinder',
)

# Make this unique, and don't share it with anybody.
SECRET_KEY = 'tbbge^_ak_4h*@sm&0_%%ys)hgf3d*nc&%ac_r0zy)!wi(lo14'

# List of callables that know how to import templates from various sources.
TEMPLATE_LOADERS = (
    'django.template.loaders.filesystem.Loader',
    'django.template.loaders.app_directories.Loader',
#     'django.template.loaders.eggs.Loader',
)

MIDDLEWARE_CLASSES = (
    'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.flatpages.middleware.FlatpageFallbackMiddleware',
    # Uncomment the next line for simple clickjacking protection:
    # 'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware',
)

ROOT_URLCONF = 'cms.urls'

# Python dotted path to the WSGI application used by Django's runserver.
WSGI_APPLICATION = 'cms.wsgi.application'

TEMPLATE_DIRS = (
    # Put strings here, like "/home/html/django_templates" or "C:/www/django/templates".
    # Always use forward slashes, even on Windows.
    # Don't forget to use absolute paths, not relative paths.
    os.path.join(PROJECT_DIR, '../templates'),
)

INSTALLED_APPS = (
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.sites',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
    'django.contrib.flatpages',
    'tinymce',
    # Uncomment the next line to enable the admin:
    'django.contrib.admin',
    # Uncomment the next line to enable admin documentation:
    # 'django.contrib.admindocs',
)

TINYMCE_JS_URL = 'http://localhost:8080/tiny_mce/tiny_mce_src.js'
TINYMCE_JS_ROOT = 'http://localhost:8080/tiny_mce'
TINYMCE_DEFAULT_CONFIG = { 
    'plugins' : "table,spellcheck,paste,searchreplace",
    'theme' : "advanced",
    'cleanup_on_startup': True,
    'custom_undo_redo_levels' : 10,
}
TINYMCE_SPELLCHECKER = True
TINYMCE_COMPRESSOR = True

# A sample logging configuration. The only tangible logging
# performed by this configuration is to send an email to
# the site admins on every HTTP 500 error when DEBUG=False.
# See http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/logging for
# more details on how to customize your logging configuration.
LOGGING = {
    'version': 1,
    'disable_existing_loggers': False,
    'filters': {
        'require_debug_false': {
            '()': 'django.utils.log.RequireDebugFalse'
        }
    },
    'handlers': {
        'mail_admins': {
            'level': 'ERROR',
            'filters': ['require_debug_false'],
            'class': 'django.utils.log.AdminEmailHandler'
        }
    },
    'loggers': {
        'django.request': {
            'handlers': ['mail_admins'],
            'level': 'ERROR',
            'propagate': True,
        },
    }
}
```

My urls.py file is as follows:

```
from django.conf.urls import patterns, include, url
from django.contrib.flatpages.models import FlatPage


# Uncomment the next two lines to enable the admin:
from django.contrib import admin
admin.autodiscover()


urlpatterns = patterns('',
    # Examples:
    # url(r'^$', 'cms.views.home', name='home'),
    # url(r'^cms/', include('cms.foo.urls')),
    # (r'', include('django.contrib.flatpages.urls')),
    (r'tinymce/', include('tinymce.urls')),

    # Uncomment the admin/doc line below to enable admin documentation:
    # url(r'^admin/doc/', include('django.contrib.admindocs.urls')),

    # Uncomment the next line to enable the admin:
    url(r'^admin/', include(admin.site.urls)),
)
```

My models.py file is as follows:

```
from django import forms
from django.contrib.flatpages.models import FlatPage

from tinymce.widgets import TinyMCE

class FlatPageForm(forms.ModelForm):

    content = forms.CharField(widget=TinyMCE(attrs={'cols': 80, 'rows':30 }))
    class Meta:
        model = FlatPage
```

My default.html is as follows:

```
<html>
<head>
<title>{{ flatpage.title }}</title>

</head>
<body>
<h1>{{ flatpage.title }}</h1>
    {{ flatpage.content }}
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to register the new form with django admin. Try replacing your models.py with this:

```
from django.contrib import admin
from django import forms
from django.contrib.flatpages.admin import FlatPageAdmin, FlatpageForm
from django.contrib.flatpages.models import FlatPage

from tinymce.widgets import TinyMCE

class MyFlatpageForm(FlatpageForm):
    content = forms.CharField(widget=TinyMCE(attrs={'cols': 80,
'rows':30 }))

class MyFlatPageAdmin(FlatPageAdmin):
    form = MyFlatpageForm

admin.site.unregister(FlatPage)
admin.site.register(FlatPage, MyFlatPageAdmin)
```

There are a couple of other things that might need to be fixed. The models.py won't be discovered if you don't have "cms" in your installed apps. Also, I think the extension you want is "spellchecker" not "spellcheck".

Comment: Thank you courageousillumination for your reply. I have now deleted models.py and replaced the plugin spellcheck with spellchecker and have changed my urls.py to the following. <https://lh6.googleusercontent.com/-tFrTIKf0tiw/UhcC5Qx2svI/AAAAAAAADGc/DZhPUdr2jXA/w866-h875-no/urls.py.png>

Comment: Although I have made these changes I still have the same problem.

Comment: In my project I also commented out TINYMCE_COMPRESSOR = True, TINYMCE_JS_URL = 'http://localhost:8080/tiny_mce/tiny_mce_src.js', and
TINYMCE_JS_ROOT = 'http://localhost:8080/tiny_mce'. I don't know if you need those, but they were causing problems for me.